# How to change font-width in javascript for every on change

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, fonts

I made a variable font that changes font-weight from 101 to 900 and would like to implement it on a website, where while the user is typing the font is changing its weight with every letter typed

I kind of have this code right now but it only changes it directly to font weight 900 and does't go slowly about it. Thanks for any help!!

```
<p id="testarea" contentEditable="true">
Type your text here
</p>


<button type="button" onclick="myFunction2()">uncensour</button>

<script>



document.getElementById("testarea").onchange = function() {myFunction()}
document.getElementById("testarea").addEventListener("input", myFunction)
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("testarea").style.fontWeight = "900";
}
function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("testarea").style.fontWeight = "101";
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define how many letter you want to show your text with weight 900.
Per example, if you want your text for 100 characters, you can use a code likes this:

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("testarea");
var relation = myInput.innerText.length / 100;
if(relation < 1){
   myInput.style.fontWeight = 100 + (relation*800);
}else{
   myInput.style.fontWeight = "900";
}
```